# How to correctly use VecDeque with capacity?

Tags: rust, deque

I'm trying to understand how `VecDeque` with capacity works in Rust:

- [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.with_capacity): "Creates an empty `VecDeque` with space for at least capacity elements."

From the following snippet i expect that if the `VecDeque` is full and I'm still **push_back** an element it will **pop_front** another element before, but it doesn't, can you help me to understand **with_capacity** usage ?

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
fn main() {
    let mut a = VecDeque::with_capacity(2);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    eprintln!("{:?}", a); //return [1, 2, 3] but i expect: [2, 3]
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2ac4bd53b3be2e4a9a3e4461a9eddd48)

Comment: Related: [How to create a VecDeque with limited size?](/q/64077048/2189130)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with English, so I express my meaning through translation tools. It may not be completely accurate

First of all, we need to know the principle that `VecDeque`(or `Vec`) can be added dynamically.

When you create it, it will apply for part of the space to store data. Suppose we apply for 7, `let mut v = VecDeque::<u8>::with_capacity(7)`,  It will apply for a space that can meet `7` `u8` data. we just created it and didn't store data, so its `capacity` is `7`, but the `len` is `0`, Because we only create the `v` and do not push to add the number. When we add data, it will be directly added to the space we apply for, When we add more than its capacity

```rust
for _ in 0..7 {
    v.push_back(1)
}
println!("{}", v.capacity()); // v.len() == 7
v.push_back(2);  // This addition will exceed the requested capacity
```

In the last `v.push_back(2)` will exceed capacity. because the underlying capacity is not enough, it needs to re apply for a larger space and copy the original data to the newly applied area. As for how much the re application is the implementation of the internal algorithm, for example, you can apply for `2 * capacity + 1`, After `v.push_back(2);` is executed, its `capacity` is 15 and `len` is 8

`When and why use with_capacity`

From the above, we can see that when we add, the capacity will be expanded when it exceeds the cap. This operation is relatively expensive.

If we can know the maximum length of `VecDeque` in advance and apply for the length as the capacity between us, then the capacity expansion operation will not occur in subsequent additions

As can be seen from the above, it will not produce the results you expect

Answer (score 7):

`with_capacity` means the initial size of the underlying memory buffer, but not the size of the collection, nor is it maintained if more items are added.

on the [`Vec` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) an important sentence is included but is missing on `VecDeque`:

> The vector will be able to hold exactly `capacity` elements without reallocating. If `capacity` is 0, the vector will not allocate.